# use rack 1.3 with rails 3.0.9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, bundler, rack

How can I use rack 1.3.0 with rails. I tried putting `gem 'rack', '1.3.0'` in Gemfile and did `bundle update rack` but it says

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rack":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 3.0.9) depends on
      rack (~> 1.2.1)

    rack (1.3.0)
```

I am having issues with rack version <= 1.2.3 here [lib/rack/utils.rb#L495](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/1.2.1/lib/rack/utils.rb#L495). I don't see this in rack 1.3.0, so wanted to give a try. But clearly rails is not allowing to use rack 1.3.

Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is: you can't use rack 1.3 with Rails 3.0. As the error states, Rails 3.0.9 depends on Rack 1.2.x with x >= 1.

If you need rack 1.3, you should try Rails 3.1 which currently depends on rack ~> 1.3.2 (i.e. 1.3.x with x >= 2). An alternative could be to change the actionpack gemspec locally to require rack 1.3. But then you are on your own and there will probably be grues coming out of holes and eating all your loved ones...

Comment: ummm... then i guess i can't use rack 1.3 with rails 3.0 . Anyway thanks!